# Managing app lifecycle state with Getx in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

what is the best approach to managing app lifecycle state?

would you do it using a getxservice with WidgetsBindingObserver?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can extend your controller class with `FullLifeCycleController` instead of `GetXController`.
`FullLifeCycleController` actually extends GetXController with WidgetsBindingObserver.

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/eduardoflorence/d918d05ad71175b52c2aca95588c305d) might help you out. :)

Comment: YourController extends FullLifeCycleController with FullLifeCycleMixin{
// GetxController
}

Answer (score 1):

Extend your controller with `FullLifeCycleController with FullLifeCycleMixin`.

### Example Code:

```dart
class HomeController extends FullLifeCycleController with FullLifeCycleMixin {

  @override
  void onInit() {
    //
    super.onInit();
  }

  // Mandatory
  @override
  void onDetached() {
    print('HomeController - onDetached called');
  }

  // Mandatory
  @override
  void onInactive() {
    print('HomeController - onInative called');
  }

  // Mandatory
  @override
  void onPaused() {
    print('HomeController - onPaused called');
  }

  // Mandatory
  @override
  void onResumed() {
    print('HomeController - onResumed called');
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        log("App Resumed");
        instantSubmit();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        log("App InActive");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        log("App Paused");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        log("App Detached");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.hidden:
        // TODO: Handle this case.
        log("Hidden");
        break;
    }
  }

}
```